# Are imports required for each SASS file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

It's been almost a decade since I coded in Rails, and I'm getting a little confused by rails `@import` practices for sass files.

Specifically: I have an `application.scss` with the following:

```
@import 'theme';
@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'colors';
@import 'sidebar';
```

In each of those files, if I want to access variables from other files, I still need to import the related scss file directly. Eg: I reference `$blue-600` (from bootstrap) in `sidebar.scss`. I'd assumed that, given bootstrap is imported above sidebar in application.scss, I wouldn't have to import it again. But I do - otherwise i get a 'variable not found' error. (Although it doesn't happen immediately on first refresh - I assume due to cached asset references, it usually takes a few minutes before the error appears).

This is problematic because I override (for example) the `$primary` color in `colors`, but when I import `bootstrap` in sidebar, bootstrap overrides my override - setting `$primary` back to its default.

So: any thoughts on what i'm doing wrong? For what it's worth, I'm using the 'bootstrap' gem and import maps to reference bootstrap, which is also precompiled in config/initializers/assets.rb. The rest of the rails 7 asset pipeline is, as far as I'm aware, pretty much default.

Other note: this is all in dev environment, I haven't sent the project to production.

Comment: Please don't tag your titles. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Update: I'm afraid I still have no idea what the underlying issue was, but somehow rails asset pipeline was importing files in a different order than specified in application.scss. ...moving to cssbundling-rails resolved it